# Gradle Task to get Android App Bundle Manifest

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-manifest, android-app-bundle

There are multiple manifests generated when we build an android project. Here is the screenshot of:

Build Directory of my application

[image]

Here if see, we can observe 3 directories, i.e.

- bundle_manifest
- instant_app_manifest
- merged_manifests

Now I observed that when build Android App Bundle, it uses **bundle_manifest**. In the case of APK, it uses **merged_manifests**. I have a code that I am injecting in my manifest through a task in build. Gradle file. Now I can use ***manifestOutputDirectory*** to get manifest directory path(i.e. merged_manifests). But I am not able to find a similar Gradle task to locate Manifest present in **bundle_manifest** directory.

Can someone help me with how to get a path for **bundle_manifest** directory?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
def manifestOutputDirectory = rootProject.getProjectDir().getAbsolutePath() +
"/${project.name}/build/intermediates/bundle_manifest/release/processReleaseManifest/bundle-manifest"
```

**But** "I have a code that I am injecting in my manifest through a task" sounds pretty strange to me.

The proper way to do it might rather be using [manifest placeholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables).

Comment: above approach works only when we have single flavour of our app. We build multiple flavours of our app based on the region. 
about "injecting in my manifest through a task", I am dynamically generating deep links through gradle file because I need to support around 35-40 deeplinks, now each deeplinks should be available for multiple language(there is change in url for each language). since list grows each time we add new language, I thought to handle dynamically. 

now ManifestPlaceholders can be replaced with a value in manifest but it doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-manage-a-complex-deeplinks-scheme-on-your-android-app-d441143cec7e
above link can give you a better idea.

Comment: Simply define the place-holders per flavor; when removing all the line-wraps, this isn't that bad. Don't think the can be done per `resConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Very old, but for somebody coming here for an answer, using:

```
bundleManifestOutputDirectory
```

gave me the path to the **bundle_manifest** directory referred to by OP