# How to check minsdkversion of generated appbundle?

Tags: android, android-bundle, android-min-sdk

i have build appbundle with minsdkversion 21. i give the file to devops for deployment, but he wants to make sure that the appbundle has minsdkversion set to 21. how do i check that? i heard [bundletool](https://github.com/google/bundletool) but how do i use this to check value of minsdkversion from my appbundle file? or maybe with other tool. thanks

in appbundle there's feature called

> Extract device spec from a device as a JSON file.

but i'm not sure how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uploading a bundle to google play console library, you can check the details of the file using App bundle explorer.

Feature that you are talking about "Extract device spec from a device as a JSON file." Creates json file that contains the specification of the currently connected android device, not the specification of the bundle.

An a easiest solution would be to provide also manifest file generated for your bundle alongside with app bundle.
You can get some more details about path of the manifest here:
[Gradle Task to get Android App Bundle Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942738/gradle-task-to-get-android-app-bundle-manifest)

Comment: i unzip the appbundle. after i check manifest file from generated appbundle, i finally could find the minsdkversion inside. thanks for mentioning it